# Unsuccessful building wxWidgets sample ( widgets sample ), in CodeBlocks

Tags: build, wxwidgets, codeblocks, windows-7-x64, build-error

I am using CodeBlocks 13.12 on a Win 7 x64 machine.
My intention was to learn a bit about building a wxWidgets project in CodeBlocks, so I created a new wxWidgets project, pointing the location of wxWidgets to "C:\wxWidgets-3.0.1" . Then added all the source files from the sample in the project and trying to build the project in the IDE, I get these errors :

```
||=== Build: Debug in widgetsSample (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxmswd_core|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxbased|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxpngd|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxzlibd|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

**How do I make corrections so that these errors disappear and project gets built ?**

As an additional info, I downloaded the ["wxWidgets-3.0.1.tar.bz2, 2014-06-15, 20.1 MB"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.1/) and followed a Youtube tutorial on compiling the sources with CMD and mingw32-make. I don't suppose that made a big difference since that only produced .O and .D files in "C:\wxWidgets-3.0.1\build\msw\gcc_mswud" folder. Well if someone cared to explain this process and its use as well I would extra appreciate it as a total beginner.

**EDIT 1:**

This is a snapshot of linker settings that I believe is relevant to the answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it you did not set the libs dir for the linker. Should be something like `Menu "Project"` -> `Build Options` -> `Linker settings`.

Compiling sources does make another big difference, see "C:\wxWidgets-3.0.1\libs".

Comment: Where are the link libs looked for? IOW what do you have under `Search directories` -> `Linker` ?

Comment: There I have "C:\wxWidgets-3.0.1\lib\gcc_lib" . One of my experiments was to rename "wxmswd_core" and "wxbased" to "wxmsw30ud_core" and "wxbase30ud", because the first 2 libs are not in the gcc_lib folder, whereas the other two are. The libs not found error was gone, but it produced near infinte number of undefined references.

Comment: Disambiguation: you're referring here to a sample created by you, not any of the samples that come with wxWidgets sources.
You need to have the same build configuration for the wxW libs AND your project. Currently from your description you've built wxW libs in Unicode-Debug configuration, but your sample is built in ANSI-Debug configuration. Make sure your sample is built in Unicode-Debug. And obviously you need to match the name of the existing libraries with the ones set in C::B.

You can also look at wxW minimal sample and get the settings from the projects or makefiles that come with it.

Comment: Sorry for writing the question in ambiguous way. The sample I am referring to, or at least the code, actually is one of the samples that come with wxWidgets sources, and it is called "widgets sample". But indeed I have created my own project in C.B. and just added the source files there, because I wanted to learn how to set up wxWidgets project in C.B.for future reference. About the rest of your explanation, I don't really understand all of it as I am a beginner, for example making sure if my sample is build in Unicode-Debug. If you can expand and "noob-explain" your answer I could accept it.

Comment: Make sure `Compiler settings` -> `#defines` contains `_UNICODE`.

Comment: Alternative: use menu `File` -> `Import project` -> `MS Visual [...]` and choose the relevant file from the sample's directory; then add/remove files to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Sure, importing MS VS project or using the sample's make file will build and run the program without issues, I did that already. But I would like to know what steps to take to make the project & program run on my own, as I will be writing my own code in future, and not always build already prepared applications. Adding _UNICODE didn't make a change, does anything else come to your mind possibly ? Thank you.